# MongoDB find an element on NodeJS returning an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working with the `MongoClient` and it would seem that whenever I try to find by query, I get an object back in return, but it works perfectly fine in the mongo terminal. This database initialization works for inputting data.

**MongoDB terminal**:

```
mongo
use player-db
db.players.find({"id":"1"})
```

**Result:** `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f3ca631950b2f4b1f157e27"), "id" : "1", "name" : "test" }`

And now in **server.js**:

```js
const url = '{ommited}'
const dbName = 'player-db'
let db;

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {

    if (err) return console.log(err)

    db = client.db(dbName)
    console.log(`Connected to Database: \n ${url}/${dbName}`)
})

/** Function that isn't working **/
const GetOne = (collection, id) => {
    let test = db.collection("players").find({"id" : "1"});
    console.log(test);
}
```

**Expected output:**
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f3ca631950b2f4b1f157e27"), "id" : "1", "name" : "test" }`

**Actual output:**

```
Cursor {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: false,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    ........................... etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently getting and logging the `cursor`.

```
    let test = db.collection("players").find({"id" : "1"}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
       console.log(docs)
    });
```

Should display your docs. `toArray` will "convert" the cursor to an array of found documents. It accepts a callback function that it will execute when it is complete. You could also you promises or async/await `await db.collection...`

Comment: I love you. You amazing individual.